# Unable to correctly interpolate using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have two array which names are y and u.
The value of  U which is end value of the u.
The value u99 which is 0.99*U

So U=11.50

u99 is 11.385

I want to interpolate u99 in the array of u to find corresponding y values. When I do with hand the  for u= 11.385 the corresponding y value is 37.32

I have two problems:

1. When I run below code It gives

   > error: Error using matlab.internal.math.interp1

Sample points must be unique

2. When I change the value of 11.50 to 11.58 this time dont give error but it gives wrong result as 62.6250 instead the result should be 37.32.

This is my MATLAB code:

```
y = [0.5 1 2 3.5 6 8 10.2 14 18 21 35 41 58 60.5 66 70 90 100];
u = [0.271 0.518 1.113 1.93 3.137 4.157 5.32 7.28 9.22 10.79 11.3 11.52 11.55 11.51 11.50 11.6 11.59 11.50];
U = u(end); % Free stream velocity
u99=0.99.*U;
L=interp1(u,y,u99);
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `interp1` works properly only if `u` is monotonic:
I've checked this with Octave, which is equivalent to Matlab.
From below example one can see that answer is `~37.32` for monotonic part of u (indices `1-13`). As soon as u becomes non-monotonic (indices `1-14`), answer becomes incorrect (`45.32`).

```
octave:1> y = [0.5 1 2 3.5 6 8 10.2 14 18 21 35 41 58 60.5 66 70 90 100];
octave:2> u = [0.271 0.518 1.113 1.93 3.137 4.157 5.32 7.28 9.22 10.79 11.3 11.52 11.55 11.51 11.50 11.6 11.59 11.50];
octave:3> interp1(u(1:13),y(1:13),11.385)
ans =  37.31818181818181
octave:4> interp1(u(1:14),y(1:14),11.385)
ans =  45.32142857142851
octave:5> u(13:14)
ans =

   11.55000000000000   11.51000000000000
```

Comment: So how I can find correct interpolate value as a 37.32  with using matlab? Please share the corresponding codes.

Comment: There is no simple answer to this question. Look at the following link: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/240599-using-interp1-on-a-function-that-is-not-monotonic-increasing